# Why does list of activity items differ in SFSafariViewController from Safari

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have an iOS application that uses the SFSafariViewController to download and display PDFs.  While viewing a PDF from the SFSafariViewController if the user presses the share button, it attempts to share the URL instead of the PDF and only displays apps that are setup to share a string.  If I then click on the Safari icon to open the same URL in the Safari app and press the share button, it attempts to share the actual PDF instead of the URL and changes the list of activity items available.  For example Google Drive is not available as an option from within my app, but is in Safari.

Is there any way to get the SFSafariViewController to work like Safari and share the content, instead of the URL?